# laravel 5 BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I receive a "BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method nowpublished does not exist."

I have a scope to receive posts only for today:

```
public function scopeNowPublished($query) {
  $query->whereBetween('published_at',[Carbon::today(),Carbon::now()])->orderBy('published_at','desc');
}
```

This works fine in my ArticleController:

```
public function index() {


  $articles = Article::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                      ->nowpublished()
                      ->get();

  $futurearticles = Article::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                            ->unpublished()
                            ->get();

  $name = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->select('name')
                ->get();

  $slug = str_slug($name, "-");

  //$articles = Article::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('published_at','desc')->get();
  return view('backend.articles.index')->withArticles($articles)->withFuturearticles($futurearticles);
}
```

I try to use this in a PagesController:

```
public function menue() {
  $articles = Article::all()->nowpublished()->get();

  return view('pages.menues')->withArticles($articles);
}
```

But it throws me the exception above. 
What's wrong here?

Comment: Try  this `Article::nowPublished()->get();` if its not working try to execute `composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
public function scopeNowPublished($query)
```

or

```
$articles = Article::all()->published()->get();
```

Comment: Sorry: my mistake it is scopeNowPublished, I edited it above. With your suggestion it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems Article::all() causes the issues. I have to chain the scope straight after. Can somebody explain why?

```
public function menue() {
  $articles = Article::nowpublished()->get();

  return view('pages.menues')->withArticles($articles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Return** query in scope function

`public function scopeNowPublished($query) {
  return $query->whereBetween('published_at',[Carbon::today(),Carbon::now()])->orderBy('published_at','desc');
}`